# Centralized Django Installations with VirtualEnv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have a server running several different Django websites, running different versions of Django. Yesterday, [Django issued security updates for 1.8 and 1.9](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2016/mar/01/security-releases/). This means that, in order to keep everything secure, I have to go to each website and update the version of Django that it's running.

Since Django does a very good job with versioning (i.e. breaking changes happen between minor versions, like 1.8-1.9, but not between releases, like 1.9.2-1.9.4), it seems like I should be able to have a central Django installation for each minor version, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, etc.

Is there a way to get VirtualEnv to target a specific installation so that I can have all the websites running Django 1.8 point at just one installation, and likewise for 1.9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use [`add2virtualenv`](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html#add2virtualenv) from virtualenvwrapper.

Simply, create some virtualenvs for shared django versions (of course, one virtualenv for one django major version) and on each of virtualenvs invoke command:

```
add2virtualenv /path/to/shared/virtualenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

replacing path to shared virtualenv (and python version if necessary) with one that you want to use.

add2virtualenv have permanent effect, so there is no need to invoke it again after activating virtualenvwrapper.

Comment: Is the functionality available outside of virtualenvwrapper? As in, can it be done with just what virtualenv makes available?

Comment: Yes, it can be done, virtualenvwrapper is simply creating `_virtualenv_path_extensions.pth` file inside `site-packages` dir of your virtualenv, that is adding specified directories into `sys.path`. By analyzing how it's exactly done in virtualenvwrapper, you will definetly be able to recreate that. But using virtualenvwrapper will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that you *could* take is to symlink django from the site-packages directory. That seems all kinds of sketchy, though.

As for myself? I'd just install [SaltStack](http://saltstack.com/), since you can [manage virtualenvs with it](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.virtualenv_mod.html)

Comment: I tried the symlink solution once and it's a bad idea because you need to hunt down other dependencies manually. What worked for me was virtualenvwrapper, which has some features that virtualenv lacks. In this scenario, I can have two virtualenvs (Django 1.8, Django 1.9, with dependecies managed by the virutalenv) and create new virtualenvs for each project and link to either the Django 1.8 or Django 1.9 virtualenv, as needed. Specifically look at the add2virtualenv command: http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html#add2virtualenv

Comment: @DRubio Wouldn't pip pick up the dependencies if you try to reinstall the specific verson?

Comment: @WayneWerner If you symlink Django, then you would need to symlink all of Django's dependencies as well. Pip would have no way to know that not all of the symlinks were made.

Answer (score -2):

Isn't this simply what requirements.txt is for? You can specify the version of Django as ">=1.8, <1.9", then you know that upgrading will always install the latest 1.8 bugfix release, but never 1.9.

Comment: That's not what the question is asking. Right now, I have X sites to go do a pip install -U "django>=1.8,<1.9" on. The question is asking how to make one centralized Django 1.8 install that all X sites use.